# JTextArea listener in Java

Tags: java, listener, jtextarea

I would like to display an item list in a JTextArea and after have the opportunity to select one in particular of these displayed items through an ActionListener and show it separately in another screen.

Is that possible in Java? In that case, which Listener should I choose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a task to use JList. Making sperate choosable items of a JTextArea String/Document would be unnessecary complicate. In JList you can use `ListSelectionListener` which fires an event whenever the selection in the list has changed. For further information see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: My pleasure - if you like you can accept this answer, by clicking on the hook on the left side ...

Comment: I have tried, but I cannot yet... I am a bit new in here. If I could I would do it for sure. Thanks again.